# "Fatal Python error: Couldn't create autoTLSkey mapping" with CherryPy

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have a CherryPy webapp that used to work nicely on Ubuntu Lucid (Python 2.6.5) but now on Ubuntu Precise (Python 2.7.3) it quits on startup with the following:

```
Listening for SIGHUP.
Listening for SIGTERM.
Listening for SIGUSR1.
Bus STARTING
Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
Fatal Python error: Couldn't create autoTLSkey mapping
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The weird thing is that this *does* work on another machine with Ubuntu Precise, so I'm guessing it's a configuration issue. [It looks like](http://groups.google.com/group/modwsgi/browse_thread/thread/0d6f929486f4eeb1/5af5795aed10a2f6?show_docid=5af5795aed10a2f6) this has something to do with threads but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found something that looks like the culprit: I have a configuration parameter that upon booting limits the webapp memory usage with a

```
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (megs * 1048576L, -1L))
```

If I remove the call or set "megs" to a value high enough (1100 in my tests) the error goes away.